# How to log progress of tasks in Talend Open Studio?

Tags: talend

I have some sample jobs that migrate data from one database to another and I would like to have some information about the current progress, like the one you have when the job is run interactively from the application itself (I export and run it from command line).
I use flowMeter and statsCatcher but everything i got is the overall time and the overall number of records passed (e.g. 4657 sec, 50.000.000 rows).
Is there any solution to get a decent log ?

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is about adding a conditional clause to logging. Something true one row every, let's say, 50000. This condition using a sequence should work:

```
Numeric.sequence("log_seq",1,1) % 50000 == 0
```

You can use the custom component [bcLogBack](http://www.talendforge.org/exchange/?eid=320&product=tos&action=view&nav=1,1,1) to basically output your log using an sl4j facade stack. The component has an option called "Conditional logging" to send the message only when the condition evaluate to true.

Alternatively, if you don't like the idea of install a custom component, you can end your subjob using the standard tLogRow (or tWarn, tDie or whatever) prefixed by a tFilter with the same expression as advanced condition. This way you'll let the stream pass (and the log message to be triggered) just one time every 50000. Here's a very basic job diagram

```
//---->tMySqlOutput--->tFilter-----//filter--->tWarn (or tLogRow)
```

Comment: tFilter seems a nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `tLogRow` outputs to the console. So you can easily plug an output into it.

If `tLogRow` isn't enough, you can plug your output into a `TJavaFlex` component. There you could use something like log4j or any custom output.

You can also use `tFileDelimitedOutput` as a log file. This component have a nice "append" option that works like a charm for this use case.

---

For your question above : **How to obtain the log information**

By experience, I can tell that some components outputs the flow. For example, the `tMysqlInput` outputs the successfully inserted rows.

Generally, to log the information I use the component `tReplicate` which allows me to output a copy of the flow to a log file.

```
 tMySqlOutput ---- tReplicate ----- tMap -------- tMySqlInput (insert in DB)
                              +---- tMap -------- tDelimitedFile (log info)
```

Comment: I don't want to log every row but only just some progress tips (like 50.000 inserted
100.000 inserted
... etc)

Comment: Keep a static variable with the amount of processed rows then outputs it when you desire. I don't think there is something ready to use.

Comment: the main problem is not how to output it but how to obtain it

Comment: There's no need for the information migrated, just for its quantity (fire a log on every commit / on every 50k records inserted), as I understand I could put a Java component after DBOutput, increment some context var and println smth on console when $var % 50.000 = 0

Comment: thank you, I thought there should be some check box (like Pentaho Kettle has) since I think it's a very common use case

Comment: If you find something please update your question. I'm upvoting since this is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use tWarn in combination with tLogCatcher:

tMySqlOutput ---- tFilter ---- tWarn

tLogCatcher ---- tMap ---- tLogRow

tFilter would prevent you from logging a progress on every row completion (see Gabriele B's answer). tWarn would have the actual message you want to log out.

tLogCatcher should get inputs from all of the tWarns, tMapper transforms each row from the logCatcher into an output row, and tLogRow logs it.

That answer is described in more detail (with pictures): http://blog.wdcigroup.net/2012/05/error-handling-in-talend-using-tlogcatcher/